# "Search All" Option in Javascript Combobox

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

I have a ext.form.Combobox object that is dynamically populated by ext.data.JsonStore. The user can type a search key to filter through the list and choose one of the filter options. I would like one clickable option in the drop down be to "All." How can I make this option *always* show up in the dynamic ComboBox list? The way it is set up now, it only shows up if the user starts typing "a..l..l.." in the search field.

Is there a search term I can apply to it that is a wild card, so it will appear no matter what the search term is?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up setting the beforeQuery property to a function that changes the search string value for the "Search All" option to whatever the current query is.

Something like..

```
combobox.on('beforeQuery', function(q) {
  searchStore.getAt(searchStore.getCount()-1).data.search_string = q.query
}
```

This works for my code because Search All option is the last one added to the search store. Otherwise, you would need to access the Search All record another way.

Answer (score 0):

The way I usually work around this is by setting the combo's `emptyText` config option to `'All'`. That way, when the combo box has no value set at all.. (and when it gets submitted to the server it will also submit an empty value), you can assume that the user doesn't want to filter on this field.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through some of the Ext3 source code, a slick way to get the functionality you want would be to override the `filterBy` function on `Ext.data.Store`, and intercept the function to allow the "All" record through:

```
Ext.ux.AllJsonStore = Ext.extend(Ext.data.JsonStore, {

    filterBy: function(fn, scope) {
        var allFn = Ext.util.Functions.createInterceptor(fn, function(record, id) {
            if (record.data.display == "All") {
                return true;
            }
        });
        return Ext.ux.AllJsonStore.superclass.filterBy.call(this, allFn, scope);
    }

});
```

Then wherever you are creating your `Ext.form.ComboBox` store, use this store instead:

```
var combo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    ...
    store: new Ext.ux.AllJsonStore({...})
    ...
});
```